# Writing an Algorithm to Represent a Bit Matrix in Minimal Operations?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, matrices

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to find the minimal representation of the transformation from a zero matrix to a target matrix.
Specifically, I have an empty matrix and can perform operations such as `set(x1,y1,x2,y2)` and `unset(x1,y1,x2,y2)` to edit submatrices.
I looked at some greedy algorithms and quadtree data structures to partition the target matrix and with those, the transformation could be represented with just `set()` operations.
That is a naive approach because of this 3x3 bit donut matrix example:

[image]

Using just `set()` you can see it is going to take a total of four operations.
However, it can also be done in one `set()` and one `unset()` which leaves me thinking about how this could even be calculated in a large matrix.

I am not sure where to begin research on this or keywords to ask google, any insights or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is NP-hard, even with only set(), and is even hard to approximate within a factor better than 2.  See https://mathoverflow.net/q/105164/37212, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/12376/5038, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516044/781723, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_covering.

A pragmatic approach might be to use a SAT solver or ILP solver.